# android shared data between onListItemClick (list, id) and listener

Tags: android

This is activity 1, here I do the implementation of my listener the method "onFabClick()"

```
@Override
public void onFabClick() {
    Intent intent = TimeOffRequestDetailsActivity.getActivityIntent(this);
    intent.putExtra(BundleKeys.MODE_TIME_OFF, TimeOffMode.USER_EDIT_CANCEL_TIME_OFF.getValue());
    startActivityForResult(intent, TIME_OFF_REQUEST_CREATE);
}
```

in my activity 2 I have the onListItemClick() this sends me important data that I need to make an edit of the list the one I need is the (id), how can I send through the listener this id of the activity 2 to the activity 1

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, v, position, id);
    CursorWrapper cursorWrapper = (CursorWrapper) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
    mListener.onFabClick();
}
```

and among my other configurations, I have a function configuring the onClick that is used in onCreate

```
private void setupAddFab() {
        View floatingActionButton = getView().findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);

            floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onFabClick();
            }
        });
    }
```

As I explained I need to send the id to the onFabClick() method in Activity 1, this method opens an Activity 3, which is where I need to use this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `onFabClick` to take the id as parameter and send it as extra when opening activity 2 like

```
@Override
public void onFabClick(int id) {
    Intent intent = 
        TimeOffRequestDetailsActivity.getActivityIntent(this);
    intent.putExtra(BundleKeys.MODE_TIME_OFF, 
        TimeOffMode.USER_EDIT_CANCEL_TIME_OFF.getValue());
    if (id != null) {
        intent.putExtra(KEY_FOR_ID, id);
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, TIME_OFF_REQUEST_CREATE);
}
```

and then modify the code that call `onFabClick`

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, v, position, id);
    CursorWrapper cursorWrapper = (CursorWrapper) 
    list.getItemAtPosition(position);
    mListener.onFabClick(id);
}
```

and

```
private void setupAddFab() {
    View floatingActionButton = getView().findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);

        floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onFabClick(null);
        }
    });
}
```